# Technical Analysis of music podcast

Tags: technique, mixing, education

Is there any podcast, channel or … that technicals analyzes music?
I already know some podcasts that analyse music and talk about context, lyrics, the singer or … I’m not looking for these things. I want to hear technical analysis of music, for ex. bassline, drums, melody, mix, …

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is ontopic and I'm not sure if I get your question right, but there are a ton of music related channels on youtube which analyse music and break down songs in various degrees. From the top of my head there are Charles Cornell, Adam Neeley, Rick Beato, David Bennett Piano...

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid questions for which the answer is just a simple list of resources are not [covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But I bet things like this exist. I just searched "music theory" in Apple Podcasts and found many results. "Music tech" didn't seem as useful, but as suggested, youtube might have more.